# Restricting css selectors to one class without repeating the class name

Tags: css

I am looking for some way to not repeat a class name within css. For example if I have

```css
.class1 div { color: red }
.class1 h2 { color: blue }
.class1 p { color: yellow }
```

is there some way I can group the 3 rules under the one class, something like

```css
.class1 {
    div { color: red }
    h2 { color: blue }
    p { color: yellow }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) (or SCSS), you can write :

```css
.class1 {
    & div { color: red }
    & h2 { color: blue }
    & p { color: yellow }
}
```

Where the '&' sign means 'write what you are actually in' (here, it means 'write .class1'). With an SASS or SCSS compiler, this will output :

```css
.class1 div {
    color: red;
}

.class1 h2 {
    color: blue;
}

.class1 p {
    color: yellow;
}
```

You can start using [Online SCSS compiler](http://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php) to start learning it without installing it. You can use the the official [Documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation) , which is pretty good, or browse Youtube to find some good tutorials.

Hope it helped !

Answer (score 0):

Rule nesting is not possible in CSS. You've to use SASS for this.